# file cannot be decoded to utf-8

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding

I have downloaded a z-machine interpreter from github made in python. (I'm using Windows 10)

https://github.com/theinternetftw/xyppy

I ran the following file: `build-single-file-version.py`, and it produced a new file in the same folder, called `xyppy.py`. The problem that I am facing is that I am not able to open this file: `xyppy.py` as I am not able to decode it back to utf-8.

I suspect that the following code in `build-single-file-version.py` is used to show the encoding for the single-file version: `xyppy.py`:

```
packed = StringIO()
packed_writer = zipfile.ZipFile(packed, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
for fname in os.listdir(package_dir):
    fpath = os.path.join(package_dir, fname)
    if os.path.isfile(fpath):
        packed_writer.write(fpath)
packed_writer.writestr('__main__.py', '''
from xyppy import __main__
if __name__ == '__main__':
    __main__.main()
''')
packed_writer.close()

pyfile = package_dir + '.py'
with open(pyfile, 'wb') as f:
    shebang = bytes((python_directive + '\n').encode('ascii'))
    f.write(shebang)
    f.write(packed.getvalue())
os.chmod(pyfile, stat.S_IRWXU | stat.S_IRGRP | stat.S_IROTH)
```

I assume that this code is used to generate the file `xyppy.py` in a certain encoding. However, I am not able to ascertain which encoding the `xyppy.py` is in, hence I am not able to open that file with Python IDLE. Can someone tell me which encoding this file would be in, and why it is encoded this way?

Edit:
when I try to open the `xyppy.py` file, the error is a prompt: "The file's encoding is invalid for Python 3.x. IDLE will convert it to UTF-8. What is the current encoding of the file?:". I have tried UTF-16 and ASCII but neither of them work.

Edit 2:
opening it with notepad gives the following (a short exerpt):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
PK    M©LQê3í  D         xyppy/blorb.py­VMoÔ0½çWX½$(´Uh¥EH…
```

Edit 3: I realise this problem may have nothing to do with encodings, can someone please explain how to make sense of the gibberish in `xyppy.py`? Would uncompressing `xyppy.py` with the `zipfile` module help?

Comment: The encoding is `ascii`, the 7-bit us-ASCII that's *identical* to the first 127 characters of UTF8. What is the actual problem? What does the generated file contain, and what does `I am not able to open this file` mean?

Comment: Open *what*? What is the problem? Python 3 strings are Unicode. That file should be UTF8 already - US-ASCII and UTF8 strings are identical. You don't have to decode anything. So what's the problem?

Comment: `zipfile.ZipFile`. That's a ZIP file, a compressed binary format. Not Python code. Does this script emit the ZIP file's contents in the `xyppy.py` file? This has nothing to do with Unicode

Comment: well, it shows as a python file. does that mean that i have decode it from the binary format back to utf-8?

Comment: It's a ZIP file. This has nothing to do with encodings. Open it with your favorite compression utility.  Or use the same library, `zipfile` do *uncompress* the contents. You still haven't shown what that file contains though.

Comment: BTW this page is UTF8. *All* web sites use UTF8. If you see weird data instead of text when you open a file, it's not UTF8 that's causing the problem

Comment: i will come back tomorrow to attempt uncompressing it. i hope it works.

Comment: @Panagiotis Not *all* web sites use UTF-8…

Comment: `io.StringIO` is text-oriented; fairly sure `zipfile.ZipFile` is binary. This shouldn't work at all. Did you mean to use `io.BytesIO`?

Comment: @deceze I know there are some ... unfortunate ... sites that still depend on the browser to detect the encoding. I'm tired of writing the history of web site encodings each time someone mistakes binary data or escape sequences for UTF8 though. I thought we left that period 18-20 years ago

Comment: @Panagiotis It's not even about the browser needing to detect the encoding. A website can be in (virtually) any encoding it wants to be in, it just needs to be correctly declared in the HTTP headers… Yes, most sane modern websites use UTF-8 because it's a good encoding because reasons; but UTF-8 isn't the only possible legitimate choice.

Comment: @deceze I know. I've lived through it. I can't believe we're going through that again - that and 2-digit years